# How to filter out noisy text for OCR in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm trying to filter out the text on return labels overlapping the address for OCR. The return label text is slightly more red and has a dithered like texture.

[image: Example image]

I've tried filtering it out using `cv::inRange` and dilation, and it works alright but I don't want to rely on hard coded colors because the lighting may change that. I had the idea of subtracting the image from a blurred version of itself and then blurring that to create a mask of areas with areas of high contrast (like the noise within the characters) but I don't know how I would implement that or if it would even work.

Comment: how exactly did that picture happen? are humans supposed to read that? -- I can tell you right now that any binarization of the raw input will ruin all the data. don't binarize at all. if there's objective reason to binarize anything ("tesseract freaks out unless..." is tesseract's failure alone), it must not happen before you've separated the picture into distinct layers.

Comment: your best option would be deep learning. train a network to react to the appearance of the different prints and separate them. that seems feasible. you'd need to come up with convincing synthetic data though. I doubt it would be fun to label enough real data. -- and of course a snapshot taken with any kind of camera won't do. you need a sharp scan of this, no warped focal plane, illumination not changing over position.

Comment: you might be able to handle this with a few inventive color space transforms... I'll give this a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: I'd consider this to be a bad photo. The focal plane doesn't coincide with the surface of that paper. You need a decent scan. Everything has to be in focus.

With some color space shenanigans, you can *barely* pull this picture apart. This relies on one of the layers being greenish while the rest of the picture is reddish.

`{0.90, 0.85, 0.80, 0.75} * R - 1.0 * G`, with some gain and bias for viewing:

[image: 0.9 red - 1.0 green]
[image: 0.85 red - 1.0 green]

[image: 0.8 red - 1.0 green]
[image: 0.75 red - 1.0 green]

I wouldn't call this quite usable though. I think you'd have more of a chance if you trained a simple neural network to separate such images. It would take the image as input (along with some color statistics) and it would emit two images that each show one "layer". You would need synthetic training data that is convincing enough. Labeling real data seems a lot of work here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've come up with a slightly better method of scanning so I'll see if I can use the color differences, and if not I'll try to train a neural network.